# Issues with windows AUC when trying to configure Apache web server

Tags: windows-7, editing

Win7 64bits up-to-date (March 7th 2013)
I get apache 2.2 installed and it worked fine in the past (weeks/month/years ago), with php5.
To day I needed apache for some tests so I run it (apache monitor). However I got an error (surprise, wasn't it OK before ?).

---

edited March 23rd :
Windows AUC was set to level 2 and that caused the described issues.
(same issues with level 1)
When I reset AUC to lowest level, things went back to normal.
So I changed the Title.

---

So I started investigating apache config files (from experience issues are often there...) and ended up totally puzzled.

1. I restarted from the *conf/orig/httpd.conf* (the saved original
   apache config file) and copied it back to *apache/conf* folder.
2. Apache starts fine.
   **However, I can't update it (why ?)**
3. So i create another *http.conf.my* in same folder to edit and play upon.
4. I remove *conf.httpd*
5. I rename *httpd.conf.my* into *httpd.conf*
6. Looks like apache works fine.
   **However** :
7. I copy *httpd.conf* into *httpd - copie.conf*
   **And then** (I am not mad as I could reproduce this several times just to beleive it) :
8. PSPAD/diffText shows:
9. *httpd - copie.conf* is exactly the same as **conf/orig/***httpd.conf* (all my modifs are lost)
10. I double check  *httpd.conf* and I can see my modifs there.
11. So what the hell happened when I copied *httpd.conf* into *httpd -
     copie.conf*  ?

I just have no idea what could go wrong.
**I checked the C: drive with windows drive check tool (requires reboot) which found no issue.**
It looks like there are two httpd.conf :
 - One (the apache original one which I copied from apache/conf/orig) which
   does not show any more in *apache/conf* and is the apache original one.
 - One (the one with my edits) which fools me

It looks like when I copy httpd.conf, win7 takes the hidden one.
I beleive apache too takes the hidden one.

**I noted too :**

1. I edit *httpd.conf* with notepad++ : I can see my edits (yes it is the content of *httpd.conf.my*. I close
2. I remove *httpd.conf*
3. I refresh the folder and indeed *httpd.conf* is not there
4. Under notepad++ file menu (file history), I can reopen *httpd.conf*
5. It shows with my edits. I edit and save
6. the file *httpd.conf* does not show in the folder
   I tried to reproduce this with another file on my desktop.
   At step 4 Notepad ++ warns that the deleted file does not exist and propose to create ...

**My questions are :**
Can anybody understand what happens ?
What can I do so solve the issue ? (= be able to edit and save my edit trustfully).

Comment: This I did already (needs reboot as drive is C: ).  However, I guess what I need is ways to investigate at low level the file system and the content of this conf folder. I don't know enough of power shell. Can someone help ?

Comment: Issues come with using windows AUC.  I set AUC to lowest level and then I could properly set apache config and run Apache.  Still the behaviour was extremely strange and reproducible.